# Javascript: 'Issue?' on updating user input in thousands figure in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am checking at this code found on a one question asked here regarding on adding of commas while user was typing a number.

```
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {
  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

~ @macek

Arrow key skip is working good and the rest.
The only problem is when you input in between or update the digits let say I enter

> "1234789"

notice that I do not have the numbers 5 and 6 in between to complete the numbers 1 to 9 now when I tried to update and enter 5 and 6 the result is **"123,457,896"**.
The reason why the 6 go to last part was the cursor moves automatically in the last part in the second key pressed.

Is there any way to make the cursor stay in its current position? I am not certain if this was because of the **keyup function** Also what I am trying to solve is how to make (CTRL + A) **Copy All** text work?

By the way I am not used in regex yet, but a deeper explanation of regex given in the example above is a plus :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : Added CTRL-Key possible AND SHIFT selection

Here is how :

```
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {
  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  if (event.ctrlKey) return;
  if (event.which == 17) return; // CTRL Key
  if (event.which == 16) return; // Shift Key

  //Get old values
  var oldPosition = $(this)[0].selectionStart;
  var oldLength = $(this).val().length;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });

  //Set caret position
  var offset = $(this).val().length - oldLength;
  $(this)[0].selectionStart = oldPosition + offset ;
  $(this)[0].selectionEnd = oldPosition + offset ;
});
```

Comment: thanks for this, @Master DJon but its lacking the ability to use ctrl key and other highlighting. I tried to add some stuffs on your work and I rewrote it without the use of jquery.

Comment: Added selection possibilities. I used jQuery because you did in your question.

Comment: It was not my code, I was just checking on it. :) btw here's what I've come up https://jsfiddle.net/04Lnkpwb/1/

Comment: Nice version ! As in mine though, it misses managing CUT and PASTE reformatting. If my answer fits your needs, you can accept it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses **toLocaleString** to reformat the number after it has been changed.  Since no locale is passed, the browser's default will be used, which should be familiar to each user.

```
document.getElementById("num-input").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var intVal = parseInt(this.value);
  if (!isNaN(intVal)) {
    this.value = intVal.toLocaleString();
  }
  console.log(this.value);
});
```